# What to do with [code] and [source-code]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, clean-up

I see a couple of tags that are similar and appear to not be used appropriately.

[code](/questions/tagged/code) has no description and over a hundred questions. It seems that many of the uses for should be [code-formatting](/questions/tagged/code-formatting) or [inline-code](/questions/tagged/inline-code). Many times it's just slapped on a question that's talking about source code of some sort. Worse, it's even used on a question tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

[source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code) is described:

> The source-code tag should be used when asking about the source-code that generates the SE sites, including all its features.

That seems odd to me. It's not like Stack Exchange is open source or that they're otherwise sharing the code. Ignoring that for the moment, it seems to be improperly used in much the same way as [code](/questions/tagged/code).

Anyway, what would be a good way to proceed to clean this up?

Answer (score 2):

The [code](/questions/tagged/code) tag now has a tag wiki excerpt. Most of the questions tagged [code](/questions/tagged/code) seem to follow the excerpt, but any that don't should be retagged. Other than that, [code](/questions/tagged/code) doesn't need any cleanup.

[source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code), on the other hand, needs some work. About 1/3 of the questions tagged [source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code) are closed, and many other questions should be tagged with [code](/questions/tagged/code) instead of [source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code). Those questions need to be retagged. A lot of the question, though, are fine to stay. Questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281342/how-does-se-creates-and-maintains-the-source-code-of-another-site-of-its-network) where the asker is just curious about how SE works internally are okay and on-topic.